# cURL in PHP: CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, setting mutiple fields with the same name?

Tags: php, curl, post

I want to encode data and pass it to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, it will have multiple fields of the same name. For example, `options[]` set to `1` and `options[]` set to `2`. I was hoping to give it a 2d array:

```
$array = [
        'options[]'=>[
            1,
            2
        ]
    ]
```

Will it work if I do this?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
```

If not, how do I pass it data that has multiple fields with the same name?

Thanks

Comment: `'options[]'` should just be `'options'`. PHP will add the `[]` automatically.

Comment: See the examples in the documentation of `http_build_query()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php